# time picker bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-timepicker

actualmente estoy buscando hacer un input de tiempo(time), pero con bootstrap... encontre este codigo en una consulta pero este codigo es para fecha y tiempo, pero yo solo quiero para tiempo(horas sin AM o PM).
este es el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>time</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    </head>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

se podra hacer con bootstrap pero solo para tiempo?

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu duda, recuerda marcarla como útil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [este enlace](https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) puedes encontrar información muy detallada al respecto.

Un ejemplo tomado de allí y que te puede servir es:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
    
    <div class="well">
      <div id="datetimepicker3" class="input-append">
        <input data-format="hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
        <span class="add-on">
          <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
          </i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
          pickDate: false
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: excelente codigo, pero tengo un incomveniente, como estoy agregando ese input en un sistema que estoy creando, hay conflicto al direccionar los .js y .css y por eso no me sale, ya que se distorciona el contenido. habra alguna manera para que esos enlaces afecten solo a ese input